# Returning properties from a Cypher Query using neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

My objective is to return two properties from two related nodes.

I want to return DataSpaceName from DataSpace and EntityName from Entity from the two nodes matched by the DataSpaceName/DataSpace property.

```
public class DataSpace
{   
 public string DataSpaceName { get; set;}        
 public string DataSpaceDescription { get; set;}
 public string ConnectionString { get; set;}
}

public class Entity
{
 public string DataConnector { get; set;}
 public string EntityName  { get; set;}
 public string EntityType  { get; set;}
 public string DataSpace{get; set;} 
}

var query = 
    client
    .Cypher
    .Match("(DataSpace:DataSpace), (Entity:Entity)")
    .Where("Entity.DataSpace = DataSpace.DataSpaceName")
    .Return ((DataSpace,Entity) => new { 
                DSName = Return.As<string>("DataSpace.DataSpaceName"),
                EName=Return.As<string>("Entity.EntityName")
                });
```

This throws an error :

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Return' does not exist in the current context
```

Instead of Return, if I use the Node (say DataSpace.As() ) I get the entire DataSpace Node.

Can somebody throw light on the mistake Im making in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've only imported the `Neo4jClient` namespace. You need to import `Neo4jClient.Cypher` as well if you want to use the `Return` class.

ReSharper would have also suggested this for you.

Comment: My Next Question. If I were to return the relation between them ( I mean the relation arc ), how do I return the same, and also what are the properties of the Relation Arc that could be used in code.